# Как перевести русские буквы в нижний регистр?

Tags: c++, c

Весь вопрос в заголовке. Пользуюсь Linux.

```
if (c >= 'а' && c <= 'п')
    c += 'А' - 'а';
else if (c >= 'р' && c <= 'я')
    c += 'Р' - 'р';
else if (c == 'ё')
    c = 'Ё';
```

Сейчас заметила, не работает просто

```
char ch = 'г';
std::cout<<ch<<std::endl;
```

Попробовала с w_char

```
w_char ch = 'г';
std::wcout<<ch<<std::endl;
```

Выводит иероглиф. В интернете есть решение с литералом L. Но его нельзя поставить перед переменной.

Comment: добавьте вопрос в вопрос

Comment: Приведите минимальную свою попытку. Коротко : установите местную локаль и вызывайте соответствующую функцию. Какого типа у вас буквы? *(`char` , `wchar_t`)*

Comment: У вас в редакторе текста программы какая кодировка?

Comment: у меня стоит UTF-8

Comment: Русские буквы занимают в памяти два байта. Так-что тип `char` не подойдёт. Есть вариант использовать только тип `wchar_t` *(2 байта)* но тогда вывод на консоль будет не простым. *(`cout` - табу ,  только `wcout`)*

Comment: Для подобной работы с русскими (и др. не ascii) буквами в utf-8 вам нужен набор простых функций, которые выбирают из строки код (unicode -- 4 байта) символа в переменную типа int и кладут их обратно (т.е. делают преобразование из utf-8 в unicode и наоборот). Естественно, сравнивать потом надо не с константой вида `'Я'` (кстати, компилятор должен был ругаться на multibyte), а с ее кодом (unicode). Преобразования utf-8 в unicode можно найти в [вике](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

Comment: `setlocale(LC_ALL,"ru_RU.UTF-8"); w_char ch = L'Г'; ch = towlower(ch);`

Comment: @AlexGlebe, `wchar_t`.

Comment: И описочки бывают ... @こきん

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ставим локаль. Используем тип буквы `wchar_t` и потоки только `wcin` ,`wcout`. Считываем букву и уменьшаем её размер.

```
# include <locale>
# include <iostream>
int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"ru_RU.UTF-8");
    wchar_t c ;
    std::wcin>>c;
    std::wcout<<L"Вход = "<<c<<std::endl;
    
    c=towlower(c);

  std::wcout<<L"Выход = "<<c<<std::endl;
    
}
```

---

```
Г
Вход = Г
Выход = г
```

Answer (score 1):

Не английские слова лучше всего обрабатывать через библиотеку ICU. Нашел примеры https://www.delftstack.com/howto/cpp/how-to-convert-string-to-uppercase-cpp/

Несколько способов оттуда. Upper заменить на lower и должно работать.

## std

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using std::cout; using std::string;
using std::endl; using std::cin;
using std::transform; using std::toupper;

string capitalizeString(string s)
{
    transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(),
                   [](unsigned char c){ return toupper(c); });
    return s;
}

int main() {
    string string1("hello there είναι απλά ένα κείμενο χωρίς");
    cout << "input  string: " << string1 << endl
         <<  "output string: " << capitalizeString(string1) << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

## ICU

Компилить с линковкой на icu

```
g++ sample_code.cpp -licuio -licuuc -o sample_code
```

Пример

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unicode/unistr.h>
#include <unicode/ustream.h>
#include <unicode/locid.h>

using std::cout; using std::string;
using std::endl; using std::cin;
using std::transform; using std::toupper;

int main() {
    string string1("hello there είναι απλά ένα κείμενο χωρίς");

    icu::UnicodeString unicodeString(string1.c_str());
    cout << "input string:  " << string1 << endl
        <<  "output string: " << unicodeString.toUpper() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Пример кода из вопроса подойдет для 8-битных кодировок вроде cp1251, cp866, koi-8. Для utf надо отбрасывать префиксы алфавитов

Comment: я сильно не уверен, что вариант "std" будет работать, если в строке находится utf-8

Comment: @KoVadim в греческом сработало судя по источнику ;) надо проверить

Comment: у @AlexGlebe сработало ж

Comment: у @AlexGlebe сработало, так как у него wchar_t. но это не utf-8. А греческий выше  по всей видимости просто 8битная кодировка...